# How we may can use Cambria and Verdana fonts on Overleaf

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I want to use Cambria fonts on the overleaf template! How I can do this? I referred to overleaf faqs but I did not get a clear idea any once can help me to do it in a simple way? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambria is not generally available but the Chrome core font Caladea is metric compatible

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\cfont{Caladea}
\newfontfamily\vfont{Verdana}

\begin{document}

One two three

{\cfont One two three}

{\vfont One two three}

\end{document}
```

[image]